# Need to add to a listview from another listview based on if 2 columns in original listview meet criteria

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code to add to one list view and then once added to the first listview the foreach goes through and adds to 4 different listviews based on conditions. Right now the code produces duplicates in the other 4 listviews and I only need it to post to each listview once based on the criteria.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] row = { taskTextbox.Text, importantComboBox.Text, urgentComboBox.Text, descriptionremarksTextBox.Text };
            var listItem = new ListViewItem(row);
            tasksList.Items.Add(listItem);
            txtClear();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in tasksList.Items)
            {
                if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "Yes" && item.SubItems[2].Text == "Yes")
                    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.SubItems[0].Text));
                else if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "Yes" && item.SubItems[2].Text == "No")
                    listView2.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.SubItems[0].Text));
                else if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "No" && item.SubItems[2].Text == "Yes")
                    listView3.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.SubItems[0].Text));
                else if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "No" && item.SubItems[2].Text == "No")
                    listView4.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.SubItems[0].Text));

                
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of current input and desired output?

Comment: So the current inputs are a textbox for a task, 2 combo boxes with each having yes/no options, and another textbox displaying the description/remarks. The output would be the task textbox depending on what the user selected in the 2 combo boxes so if they selected yes and yes it will output the accompanying task to the first listview. If they select yes and no it will output the accompanying task to the second listview. If they select no and yes it will output the accompanying task the third listview. and if they select no and no it will output the accompanying task to the fourth listview.